# Google Map Api Invalid Value Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have created the following code using Google Maps API that should make a direction line on Google Maps between two given addresses. My Code is:

```js
function initMap()
{
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });

   var directionsService  = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }); 
  
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   
   var pointA,pointB;
   

        geocoder.geocode({'address': document.getElementById('addressFrom').value}, function(results, status) {
  var location = results[0].geometry.location;
  pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(),location.lng());
  alert(location.lat() + '' + location.lng());
  });
  

        geocoder.geocode({'address': document.getElementById('addressTo').value}, function(results, status) {
  var location = results[0].geometry.location;
  pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(),location.lng());
  alert(location.lat() + '' + location.lng());
  });
 
 var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    });
 
 var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    });
 
 calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="addressFrom" type="textbox" value="Sydney">
<input id="addressTo" type="textbox" value="London">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="initMap">
<div id="map"></div>
```

I get the following errors when inspecting from the browser:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Directions Service Displaying Text Directions Repeating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406549/google-maps-api-directions-service-displaying-text-directions-repeating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geocoder is asynchronous, the results don't come back until after you place the call to the directions service.

A hint is this error in the javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'l' of null

Chain the geocoder calls (not sure why you need those, the directions service takes addresses just fine), move the call to the directions service into the callback function for the second geocode operation (so both locations are available when the directions service is called).

Another problem is you can't drive from Sydney to London.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
  });

  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var pointA, pointB;


  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': document.getElementById('addressFrom').value
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status != "OK") return;
    var location = results[0].geometry.location;
    pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
    alert(location.lat() + ',' + location.lng());
    var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    });
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': document.getElementById('addressTo').value
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status != "OK") return;
      var location = results[0].geometry.location;
      pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat(), location.lng());
      alert(location.lat() + ',' + location.lng());
      var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pointB,
        title: "point B",
        label: "B",
        map: map
      });
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);
    });
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="addressFrom" type="textbox" value="Sydney" />
<input id="addressTo" type="textbox" value="London" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="initMap()" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function `calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);` the positions `pointA`and `pointB` are undefined because they are the result of the asyncronous call of `geocoder.geocode`.

Move the `calculateAndDisplayRoute` function call after you've obtained a result from `geocoder.geocode`

```
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': document.getElementById('addressTo').value
  }, function(results, status) {
    var location = results[0].geometry.location;
    poi

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);
    }
```

Since you're sending two geocoding requests you will need to wait for the geocoder status for each request.